# jQuery adding dynamically autosize textarea

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to implement this : https://github.com/jackmoore/autosize/tree/v1

It works as expected when I add a textarea on my html page, but it doesn't work as expected it if I create a textarea dynamically. You can click "new comment" and test it.

Here's my fiddle.
http://jsfiddle.net/hcxgqhae/6/

HTML

```
<!-- REGULAR TEXTAREA, it works -->
<textarea></textarea>
<br>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-success new-comment">New comment</button>
<div class="detailBox">
    <div class="actionBox">
        <ul class="commentList">
            <li>
                <div class="commenterImage">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/6" />
                </div>
                <div class="commentText">
                    <p class="">Hello this is a test comment.</p> <span class="date sub-text">on March 5th, 2014</span>
 <span class="getsocial"><a href="">like</a></span>
 <span class="getsocial"><a href="">comment</a></span>
 <span class="getsocial"><a href="">share</a></span>

                </div>
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="commenterImage">
                    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/7" />
                </div>
                <div class="commentText">
                    <p class="">Hello this is a test comment and this comment is particularly very long and it goes on and on and on.</p> <span class="date sub-text">on March 5th, 2014</span>

                    </div>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <div class="commenterImage">
                        <img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/9" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="commentText">
                        <p class="">Hello this is a test comment.</p> <span class="date sub-text">on March 5th, 2014</span>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        autosize(document.querySelectorAll('textarea'));
    </script>
```

CSS

```
.detailBox {
    border: 1px solid #bbb;
}
.titleBox {
    background-color: #fdfdfd;
    padding: 10px;
}
.titleBox label {
    color: #444;
    margin: 0;
    display: inline-block;
}
.commentBox {
    padding: 10px;
}
.commentBox .form-group:first-child, .actionBox .form-group:first-child {
    width: 80%;
}
.commentBox .form-group:nth-child(2), .actionBox .form-group:nth-child(2) {
    width: 18%;
}
.actionBox .form-group * {
    width: 100%;
}
.taskDescription {
    margin-top: 10px 0;
}
.commentList {
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
.commentList li {
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.commentList li > div {
    display: table-cell;
}
.commenterImage {
    width: 30px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    height: 100%;
}
.commenterImage img {
    width: 100%;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
.commentText p {
    margin: 0;
}
.sub-text {
    color: #aaa;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.actionBox {
    padding: 10px;
}
.commentText p {
    margin-left: 0.2em;
    font-size: 0.9em;
}
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.new-comment').one('click', (function () {
        $('.commentList li:last').after('<li> ' +
            '<div class="commenterImage"> ' +
            '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/6"/> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '<div class="commentText"> ' +
            '<p class=""><textarea></textarea></p> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</li>');
    }));
});
```

Comment: _It works as expected when I add a textarea on my html page, but it doesn't work as expected it if I create a textarea dynamically_ Can you explain bit more on this?

Comment: Of course. Please look at the difference between the existing textarea and the new one when you click new comment. While the first one is able to expand horizontally when you type something in it, the second one isn't.

Comment: you need to `autosize` the new textarea

Comment: @Neverever, how? That's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to autosize the new textarea

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.new-comment').one('click', (function () {
        var li = $('<li> ' +
            '<div class="commenterImage"> ' +
            '<img src="http://lorempixel.com/50/50/people/6"/> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '<div class="commentText"> ' +
            '<p class=""><textarea></textarea></p> ' +
            '</div> ' +
            '</li>');

        $('.commentList li:last').after(li);

        // `autosize` the new textarea
        autosize(li.find("textarea"));
    }));
});
```